# `initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

The error is:

```
./batch_build.rb:83:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)  
  from ./batch_build.rb:83:in `open'
  from ./batch_build.rb:83:in `<main>'
```

Which line 83 refers to:

```
IO.open("xcodebuild -scheme Runner archive -archivePath '/tmp/#{BUILD_DIR}' -UseNewBuildSystem=NO -allowProvisioningUpdates") do |line|

    hasError = true if line.downcase.include? 'error' # line 85

    `xcode /tmp/#{BUILD_DIR}/Runner.xarchive` # line 87

end # line 89
```

Which the related lines are:

```
KEY_FILE = 'android/key.properties'
verCode = `cat #{KEY_FILE} | grep versionCode | cut -d '=' -f 2`.to_i
verCode += 1
BUILD_DIR = "xyz_#{verCode}"
```

What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

Dammit, it should be `popen` instead of `open`, 
also missing `.each` before `do` on that line 83.

Hmm.. Should I erase this question?

Comment: More times than not I find my problem a few minutes after posting the question :)  I think going thru the details helps.

Comment: yeah i think the term is `rubber duck programming` or something.. '__')